# Exporting browser history from Firefox to Tor Browser

Tags: firefox

I've been contemplating switching from Firefox-with-Tor to the actual Tor Browser, but while exporting the bookmarks is straightforward, I haven't figured out yet how to export my rather lengthy browser history from the former to the latter. Can anyone help, please?

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data

This is a firefox question, not about tor at all. Flagging this for closure.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a firefox support question.

Comment: I beg to differ. It is technically about Tor Browser as well, since another way of phrasing the question is "How do I import browsing history from other browsers (Firefox or otherwise) into Tor?"

Comment: Tor Browser is firefox. You're going to break a lot of its protections and contaminate it by importing history. You can disagree, I'm still voting to close it. The answer to your question is in the link in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, you just have to [copy your profile directory](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data).